# How can I print a PDF client side that was received from my server?

Tags: node.js, express, pdfmake

So I'm very new to generating PDFs from the server side as I have generally always created them from the client side.  I decided to migrate to creating them strictly server side because I believe there is more flexibility doing it this way.  One thing that I have been struggling with lately is that I'm trying to generate a PDF from the server and then retrieve the data on the client side and be able to print it from there.

I'm using the `pdfmake` library to generate my PDFs on the server. You can see that I'm using a get request to retrieve the generated PDF here:

```
server.get(`/api/print_paper_letter`, bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}), async (req,res) => {
            try {
                const doc = await PrintPaperLetter(req.body.pdf_obj);
                res.type('application/pdf');
                res.send(doc);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(`api.print_paper_letter: ${e}`);
                res.sendStatus(400);
            }
        });
```

And I'm generating the PDF from another file here:

PrintLetter.js

```
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
import {PaperLetterNormal} from '../../components/PDFTemplates';

const fonts = {
    Helvetica: {
        normal: 'Helvetica',
        bold: 'Helvetica-Bold',
        italics: 'Helvetica-Oblique',
        bolditalics: 'Helvetica-BoldOblique'
      }
}

export const PrintPaperLetter = async (pdf_obj) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
            const definition = PaperLetterNormal(pdf_obj);
            const pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(definition);
            let chunks = [];
            pdf.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
            pdf.on('end',() => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
            pdf.end();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`PaperLetters.PrintPaperLetter: ${e}`);
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}
```

When I make the call to retrieve the PDF data from the client side I end up getting some sort of garbage data, but I'm not sure how I would be able to print this.

Client side code:

```
const pdf_obj = {
  .
  .
  .
}

$.post('/api/print_paper_letter',{pdf_obj: pdf_obj},(res) => {
                    if(!res){
                        console.error(`there was an issue retrieving this pdf doc`)
                    }else{
                        console.log({res});
                    }
                })
```

The response on the client side looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.3
%ÿÿÿÿ
9 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/ca 1
/CA 1
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/CA 1
>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/ca 1
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
/Contents 6 0 R
/Resources 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/ExtGState <<
/Gs1 9 0 R
/Gs2 11 0 R
/Gs3 13 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
/I1 5 0 R
>>
/Font <<
/F1 10 0 R
/F2 12 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Length 2896
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xÍ]ÛrÇ
}ß¯P»ÑúR¥âíÄ?¤*±Þ\~Ë\*J*QUòû9îÎ» i.d¦¤
û hà}M_ï¿t¡ÔÇ´ý¼ùæ/4ýåËæßÒ¼GjCõIòÔìå?Ðôý¿6:üÔ7ßïþû·íîÏ?|;m¿lö?ÿeûÏÍÝ3Þâ9¾ý°<§^8uÜËôø¿§òôánóó{V|ço¦üËôáÇÍï><K²§q«¦\h¥¦êmô4;ÐB76,ï[½Nï«ÞLßËîfªx QMâ
ìD#pSjMjºöT«gÄ
Ö·Àî9=ÑqT8ÉSømkÇÐº
ÂÁ5º[ÙEà*§ª¾ÛQf¨¾^[2§æ@·ù¿Eí;-üû1´rco½¯Ù0ê]ÝÛë×%ëRCgëØA-¾[&Þ,5þâ®ÊV¦ÿm~þ·èïøþqGYÉx>o´éúÁ?Öýøî§¥?}÷Gëg±~þtu­{Q×#FÃÞÛô÷ÎÜ8'.ÍÅûn%
­H·GüÖÂ\Íh©UrÄáÂãcÕÈÂ
þÐ_Í¬0¯ÒhtNÝhA²¡Zêà+Û4[ÉI{½oÀS¬w{jÔê>Z·«In©IÆ÷Ð%m%Bà\/K á°#»&xHù¤£;¸QùãÍ¤Qláwª§ó¬æy2é[RÎ]ÏûVBèt­x¦¶
{D¼kOàÂOô°nà´Þâ{â1IGêÅ%9æãahÁzº¯{Æ'!@É5isû?öá2ÌËbB§n³þ²f39F´ÚÕ!D'¸Üñ[Ù\j,P³Äj ­ÙÝÏxëÇígD§2rÐIñé|¶å'Ë´ î§kÁÉpÑ©ÊóÉìH0p××XoìÉ¡yºÝ\?`UJ¤Ýë¿´ÉX®æD|dÎ½5$IË¹ßþ°:GüÒEgÒ;0qfIª0HdRÏLa(bÌä0Ý*%Ñîàòg¹
¨~!U-ÕÞ²®ï
.
.
.
```

If someone could explain to me what I'm looking at in terms of the response, and if it's possible to convert this in a way to then print it on the client side, that would be amazing.  Please let me know if you need me to add more to my post.  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

When you send a pdf response, you are sending a blob/buffer to the front-end, so you'll need to capture that in the front-end to display/download the content.

if you want to immediately prompt for download, add `res.attachment(filename)` to your express function.

**EXPLANATION:**

`res.attachment()` does the same as the native node `response.setHeader()` command. It sets the `content-disposition` header property to `attachment`, additionally setting the fil-name, if supplied with one.
After that, to actually serve the file, you call the `res.send()` method to end the process and send the response, as you do with any request.

Alternatively, if you want to render the file on the client you will need to use a compatible element like the (relatively new) HTML [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object), or another compatible element.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will try the express solution to see if that works.

Comment: I tried adding ```res.attachment(doc)``` to my express method but it gives me an error saying that the "path" argument must be of type string.  I don't think this will work considering I'm not saving this document as a static file, instead I'm just generating it and then passing it to the client to receive.

Comment: The "path" is simply a document name, not necessarily an actual file path. See [here](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.attachment)

Comment: Ok thanks.  So do I call ```res.send(doc)``` after calling ```attachment```? Or does express already know the data that i'm passing?

Comment: Ok, so I'm currently doing ```res.attachment('./test_pdf.pdf')``` then ```res.send(doc)```, but nothing is downloading.  I'm not getting any errors though which means it must be working, but I can see the file anywhere.

Comment: Can you console  log your res & res.data objects and see what it contains?

Comment: consoling res comes up with a huge list of properties as I would have assumed, but res.data shows ```undefined```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232833/discussion-between-isae-and-michael).

Comment: I also set the attachment on. the header but pdf does not get downloaded. Did you solve this @mi